# PHPMailer и форма обратной связи на всех страницах?

Tags: php, html5, phpmailer

Сайт каталог с большой вложенностью папок, каждая категория товара и карточки товара это отдельный html, все структурировано, так просил сам заказчик. Сейчас заказчик попросит добавить форму обратной на все станицы сайта (300+ станиц). Получается мне надо закидывать форму form.php и папку с библиотекой PHPMailer во все папки проекта?
Это грубо говоря корень, на этих страницах mailer работает, т.к. и форма и папка PHPMailer лежат здесь ->
[image: Корень сайта]

Чтоб форма заработала, мне придется закидывать папку с библиотекой PHPMailer и form.php ко всем html, а таких страниц 300+,
[image: Файловая структура карточки товара]

Можно как нибудь сделать чтобы библиотека и form.php лежали в корне без копирования этих фалов во всю структуру сайта, и чтобы форма работала на всех страницах сайта?

Comment: "Можно как нибудь" --- можно. Вы уже сами описали что именно нужно делать

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос проще я обработчик формы, шаблон для письма и библиотеку PHPMailer положил в корень сайта, в самом пути до формы в страничках прописал путь относительно корня сайта  `<form action="/form.php" name="form" method="POST" id="form">` , и все сработало, не надо ничего копипастить.